# Not able to scroll simple html page

Tags: html, css

Ive ran into a problem with my CSS code, using overflow-y: scroll; the page should be scrollable, yet it isn't. I filled the page site with lorem ipsum so there should be more than enough content for a scroll bar. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(65, 75, 100);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button type="button" id="btn1">
            <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
          </button>
  <!---->
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" id="btn2" class="dropbtn">
              <a class="material-symbols-rounded">menu</a>
            </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
      <p><a href="overmij.html">Over mij</a></p>
      <p><a href="mijnprojecten.html">Mijn projecten</a></p>
      <p><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
  <h1 id="mijnportfolio">MIJN PORTFOLIO</h1>
</div>
<style></style>
<h3 id="loremipsum">
  /* lorem ipsum here */
</h3>
<div class="footer">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It still requires enough content to actually scroll, otherwise the scrollbar will be there but inactive. What does the HTML look like in this example?

Comment: try adding a `min-height` to the elemint inside the body which is greater than `100vh`

Comment: How does you HTML look, need more info to answer the question.

Comment: Your code appears to work for me. (Also, an `<a>` inside a `<button>` is invalid HTML)

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
   body {
 background-color: rgb(65, 75, 100);
 background-position: 0 0;
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 min-height: 1200px;
}
</style>
```